# To prove that the sum of the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix is equal to the trace of the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How do we prove that the sum of the roots of the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix is equal to the trace of the matrix ? I want a proof which does not use much computation or determinants ; please help , Thanks in Advance .

Comment: How do you define the characteristic polynomial of a square matrix?

Comment: @lhf : Good point.

Answer (score 7):

**Step 1.** If $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices then
${\rm Tr}(AB)= {\rm Tr}(BA)$.

**Step 2.** If $A$ is an $n\times n$ complex matrix, then there is a triangular matrix $T$, and an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}TP$, hence
$${\rm Tr}(A)={\rm Tr}(P^{-1}TP)={\rm Tr}(P P^{-1}T )={\rm Tr}(T)$$
But the diagonal elements of $T$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

**Remark.** This works on any field if the characteristic polynomial can be split into the product of first degree polynomials. And the result is wrong otherwise.

Comment: You mean with $D$ the diagonal of $T$ then $\det(xI-A) = \det(P^{-1} (xI-T) P)= \det(xI-T)=\det(xI-D) = \prod_{j=1}^n (x-D_{j,j})$ and $Tr(A) = Tr(P^{-1} T P) = Tr(TP^{-1}P) = Tr(T) =Tr(D)= \sum_{j=1}^n D_{j,j}$

Answer (score 2):

It is direct if you use [Schur's decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)

That is, for any square matrix $A$ with complex entries, there exist unitary matrix $U$ such that $U^{-1}A\ U$ is an upper triangular matrix with eigenvalues in the diagonal. Therefore the sum of eigenvalues = trace of $U^{-1}A\ U$ = trace of $A$

---

If you don't know Schur's decomposition yet, try to prove it on your own! It's a lot of fun. Try using induction, similarly with the proof that every Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch of an elementary answer.

Let $p$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$. Then
$$
p(\lambda)=\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}-\lambda & a_{12} &\cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}-\lambda &\cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\cdots & a_{nn}-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|=(-1)^n\lambda^n+b_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+b_0
$$
The sum of the roots of $p$ is $(-1)^{n-1}b_{n-1}$.
Note that 
$$
p^{(n-1)}(\lambda)=(-1)^nn!\lambda+(n-1)!b_{n-1}.
$$
Now try to find the $(n-1)-$derivative of the determinant
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}-\lambda & a_{12} &\cdots & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}-\lambda &\cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\cdots & a_{nn}-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|$$
After some tedious calculations we get the the answer.

Note that the first derivative of the determinant is
$$
\left|\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 \\
a_{21} & a_{22}-\lambda &\cdots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} &\cdots & a_{nn}-\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|
+\cdots+
\left|\begin{matrix}
a_{11}-\lambda & \cdots & a_{1n-1} & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & & & \vdots \\
a_{n-1,1} & \cdots & a_{n-1,2}-\lambda & a_{n-1,n} \\
0 & \cdots &0 & -1
\end{matrix}\right|
$$

Comment: The OP said no determinants...