# Relation between a finite group and the Galois group for the field extension generated by the character table entries

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, galois-theory, characters

Let $E$ be the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ generated by the character table entries of a finite group $G$.
Let $F$ be the Galois closure of $E$.

*Examples*:
- $G=C_n$,  $E=F=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times} \simeq Out(G)=Aut(G)$,
- $G=S_n$, $E=F=\mathbb{Q}$ and so $C_1 = Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \hookrightarrow Out(G)$ and $Aut(G)$,
- $G=A_n$ with $3 \le n \le 5$, $E=F$ and $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq Out(G) \simeq C_2  \hookrightarrow Aut(G)$,
- $G=A_6$, $E=F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq C_2 \hookrightarrow Out(G)\simeq  C_2 \times C_2 \hookrightarrow Aut(G)$.

**Question**: Is it true in general that  $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ or $Aut(E/\mathbb{Q}) \hookrightarrow Out(G)$ or $Aut(G)$?
If not, is there at least a non-trivial homomorphism from $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ to $Aut(G)$? Or any relation?

*Bonus question*: Is there an example with $E \subsetneq F$?

Comment: $n=|G|$ an homomorphism $\rho : G \to GL_m(\Bbb{C})$ and $\det(xI-\rho(g))= \prod_j (x-\alpha_{g,j})$ then $\rho(g)^n = I$ implies the minimal polynomial divides $x^n-1$ [so that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947029/to-prove-that-the-sum-of-the-roots-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-of-a-square) $\alpha_{g,j} = \zeta_n^{e_{g,j}}$ and $Tr(\rho(g)) = \sum_j \alpha_{g,j} \in \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and $E/\Bbb{Q}$ is abelian

Comment: @reuns: Can we deduce that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})$ is a subgroup of $G$, or something like that?

Comment: No, it is a quotient (thus a subgroup since we are in finite abelian group) of $\Bbb{Z/nZ}^\times = Gal(\Bbb{Q(\zeta_n)/Q})$ and $\Bbb{Z/e Z}^\times$ where $e$ is the exponent of $G$. Also $E$ is called the minimal [splitting field](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_field)

Comment: The character table of dihedral group $D_6$ non-abelian with $6$ elements is integer valued so you can't deduce $E$ only from $n$ or $e$

Comment: There are nonisomorphic groups with the same characters so you can't hope to deduce $G$ from $E$ or $F$

Comment: @Max: I did not expect to deduce $G$ from $E$ or $F$, but something like: $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q})$ embeds into $Aut(G)$.

Comment: @reuns: [Minimal splitting field need not be unique](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_splitting_field_need_not_be_unique), [Field generated by character values need not be a splitting field](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Field_generated_by_character_values_need_not_be_a_splitting_field), [Field generated by character values is splitting field implies it is the unique minimal splitting field](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Field_generated_by_character_values_is_splitting_field_implies_it_is_the_unique_minimal_splitting_field)

Comment: Yes I was reading about that, (over $\Bbb{Q}$) the field $E$ generated by characters of irreducible reps $G \to GL_.(\Bbb{C})$ is a subfield of $L$ where all irreducible representations exist as $G \to GL_.(L)$. In some cases $E = L$, in some cases $E \subsetneq L$ (example quaternions $Q_8$). $E$ is unique, $L$ needs not be unique.

Comment: @reuns: $L$ is not unique (as we can always take $\Bbb{C}$), but the minimal such field should be unique as the field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ generated by the entries of all the matrices for all the irreducible complex representations of $G$.

Comment: No that's what is explained in https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_splitting_field_need_not_be_unique if $g\mapsto \rho(g)$ is a representation then so is $g \mapsto P \rho(g) P^{-1}$, sometimes two different $P$ give two different minimal splitting field $L$ (you can take $\rho$ to be all the irreducible representations in block diagonal so it suffices consider only one $\rho$). The irreducible representations can be represented over $E$ but sometimes only with multiplicity $> 1$ making them non-irreducible

Comment: @reuns Why don't you wrap all this up in an answer below. You made very good remarks.

Comment: If $K'/K$ is a finite extension, then $K'/K$ is a Galois extension iff $K'$ is a splitting field over $K$ (Theorem 16.6.4 in the second edition of Artin's book).

Comment: If $|G|=n$ then the character values in the character table lie in the abelian extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$; so, doesn't it imply that $E$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? And so $F$ will be $E$?

Answer (score 1):

For the Mathieu group $G=M_{11}$, we have $E=\mathbb{Q}(i\sqrt{2},i\sqrt{11})$ (see the character table [here](https://nickpgill.github.io/MMath_Sam.Hughes.pdf) p. 89), whereas $Out(G)=C_1$. It follows that $Gal(F/\mathbb{Q}) \not \hookrightarrow Out(G)$.

Otherwise the following sentence comes from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_table#Outer_automorphisms):

> The outer automorphism group acts on the character table by permuting
>   columns (conjugacy classes) and accordingly rows, which gives another
>   symmetry to the table.